# What's wrong in this program to remove extra spaces?

Tags: c

I tried to write a program to remove extra spacing. But it never returned the desired output. Can I know what's wrong here and how I can correct it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char strin[150];
    int n,i;
    printf("Number of words : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter Input: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&strin[i]);

    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strin[i]==" ")
            continue;
        else
            printf("%c",strin[i]);
    }
}
```

Also I tried using %s instead of %c (with string.h header) but the run cmd crashed upon running it. Why does it crash?

Comment: You absolutely need to think about the terminating `'\0'` when dealing with strings!

Comment: You ask for "number of words" ... but `n`, looking at the code, represents *number of characters*.

Comment: Suggestion: turn on, and mind, the maximum warnings your compiler can produce.

Comment: using ```if(strin[i]==' ')``` removed all and any spacing in the input. Now, How do I add only one space between them?

Comment: Compile your C code `augustus.c` above with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g augustus.c -o augustus-prog`. You should get many warnings. Improve `augustus.c` to get none. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Answer (score 1):

Use `' '`  instead of `" "` for checking a single character.

Use `strcmp()` to check more than one characters or whole string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all spaces in the string and store it instead of just printing it, you can use this simple function:

```
void rmspaces(char *str)
{
    const char *dup = str;
    do {
        while (isspace(*dup)) {
            ++dup;
        }
    } while (*str++ = *dup++);
}
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
rmspaces(str);
```